# 18.04 Boot to black unless I delete $vt_handoff grub parameter, related to Nvidia drivers?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia

I started having problems booting after I tried to use `prime-select` for the first time to switch between my laptop's Nvidia GTX 960M and Intel graphics, using the same `nvidia-390` driver that had worked fine for months.

The computer would boot to black, then to tty if I put `nomodeset` in grub, then after reading a zillion Ask Ubuntu pages and reinstalling a lot of packages, I did `sudo apt purge *nvidia*` and switched to the new `nvidia-driver-415`. I also added `nouveau.modeset=0` to `/etc/default/grub`.

Now it boots and runs fine, but only if I manually edit grub every time I boot and remove the `$vt_handoff` parameter that shows up after `nouveau.modeset=0`. If I don't, it boots to black, and I can't even get a tty. What gives?

Doing some digging, I found an [old bug report](http://pasted.co/91da2cda) that suggests that a missing `/boot/grub/gfxblacklist.txt` file could disable a graphical boot. I don't have that file. I considered installing `grub-gfxpayload-lists` as suggested by that post, but it looks like it might conflict with more recent grub-related packages and wreck shop. I'm relatively new to linux and hesitant to mess around with the guts of the OS in case I break something I don't understand.

Any ideas? I would greatly appreciate any help.

More details, let me know if I can include anything else:
Dell Inspiron 7559, dual boot with Windows 10 (Secure Boot off);
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS;
kernel 4.15.0-39-generic;
graphics Nvidia GeForce GTX 960M/PCIe/SSE2;
GNOME 3.28.2;
`/etc/default/grub` : [link](http://pasted.co/91da2cda)